# Scala: access "static" member of bounded generic type

Tags: scala, abstract-class, abstract-type, bounded-types

I want to achieve the following:

```
abstract class Super {
  def typeSpecific: Int
}

class SubA extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 1
}
class SubB extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 2
}

class Tester[T <: Super] {
  def test = T.typeSpecific
}

val testerA = new Tester[SubA]
val testerB = new Tester[SubB]

testerA.test // should return 1
testerB.test // should return 2
```

Is something like this possible in Scala? This fails because the value of `T` is not found in `Tester.test`.

Comment: Scala does not have any concept of "static" in the sense of the Java keyword

Comment: I agree! I've putted "static" in quote marks in the title so it hopefully makes the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeSpecific` is not a static member, it belongs to instances of `SubA` and `SubB`, which you don't have. You also can't statically access anything from a type parameter (it's a type, not an object).

This won't work as is, because you don't have instances of `SubA` and `SubB`, nor can you obtain them via `new Tester[SubA]`. But you can require that `Tester` mixes in a type of `Super` in order to make it one (and thus have `typeSpecific`). This would require you change `Super`, `SubA`, and `SubB` to traits, and would also make your instance anonymous classes.

```
trait Super {
  def typeSpecific: Int
}

trait SubA extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 1
}
trait SubB extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 2
}

// The self-type `this: A =>` requires the mix-in.
class Tester[A <: Super] { this: A =>
  def test = typeSpecific
}

val testerA = new Tester[SubA] with SubA
val testerB = new Tester[SubB] with SubB

scala> testerA.test
res2: Int = 1

scala> testerB.test
res3: Int = 2
```

You could also require `A <: Super` as a constructor parameter for `Tester`, which is probably the cleaner option.

```
abstract class Super {
  def typeSpecific: Int
}

class SubA extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 1
}
class SubB extends Super {
  def typeSpecific = 2
}

class Tester[A <: Super](s: A) {
  def test = s.typeSpecific
}

val testerA = new Tester(new SubA)
val testerB = new Tester(new SubB)

scala> testerA.test
res5: Int = 1

scala> testerB.test
res6: Int = 2
```

Any way you cut it, you're going to need an instance of `SubA` or `SubB`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use reflection combined with typeTags to get your desired result. I warn you, it's somewhat ugly:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class SuperClass {
  def typeSpecific: Int
}

class SubA extends SuperClass {
  def typeSpecific = 1
}
class SubB extends SuperClass {
  def typeSpecific = 2
}

class Tester[T <: SuperClass: TypeTag] {
  def test = typeTag[T].mirror.runtimeClass(typeOf[T]).newInstance.asInstanceOf[T].typeSpecific
}
```

I also feel I should mention that typeSpecific is not static as it is part of a class, in scala static members are defined in objects/companion objects only. Using objects it would be cleaner to do something like this:

```
trait SuperTrait {
  def typeSpecific: Int
}

object SubA extends SuperTrait {
  def typeSpecific = 1
}
object SubB extends SuperTrait {
  def typeSpecific = 2
}

class Tester(testObject : SuperTrait) {
  def test = testObject.typeSpecific
}

new Tester(SubA).test
new Tester(SubB).test
```